# "fd:6: hGetLine: end of file" in Cryptol

Tags: cryptol

I've compiled and installed both cvc4 from source code. Cvc4 was downloaded and installed as suggested, and Cryptol was downloaded from it's git repository. The sandboxing, and installation finished without error (with GHC 7.8.3 x86_64). The issue occurs only after invoking `cryptol`, and issuing a `:prove True`. Here is everything:

```
athan@namek ~/lib> cryptol
                        _        _
   ___ _ __ _   _ _ __ | |_ ___ | |
  / __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \| |
 | (__| |  | |_| | |_) | || (_) | |
  \___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___/|_|
            |___/|_| version 2.1.0 (8898348)

Loading module Cryptol
Cryptol> :prove True
cryptol: fd:6: hGetLine: end of file
athan@namek ~/lib>
```

Any help with this would be tremendous. To me, it feels like there's a shared library not found. Would that cause this issue? Thank you.

Comment: The strong implication here is that the CVC4 installation is broken (also, cryptol should be doing a better job of checking the installation and catching errors).

Comment: Indeed, this strongly reminds me of when I had a bad boolector installation [here](https://github.com/GaloisInc/cryptol/issues/105).  So we do have an issue filed to address this "bug" but in the mean time you should verify your CVC4 installation is actually broken and fix that.

Comment: Strange, I ran a `make test` and it looks like everything passed. Here's the last 30 lines or so of `make test` : http://lpaste.net/114668

Comment: Just to be entirely clear, you can run `cvc4` from the command line and get output such as: http://lpaste.net/114671 ?

Comment: Yep, I can do that just fine :S

Comment: Also, did you build 32 bit or 64?

Comment: @ja: So I've got version 1.4 running, I compiled it from the source tarball distributed on [this page](http://cvc4.cs.nyu.edu/builds/src/). I'm running a `x86_64-unknown-gnu`, and it was compiled with GCC version 4.8.2.

Comment: To answer one of your questions explicitly, yes a shared library missing can cause this.  Such an error usually arises when the SMT, in this case CVC4, exists but fails to execute.  I would look for things that might be different between your manual invocation of CVC and Cryptol's invocation (LD_LIBRARY path, binary path, etc).

Comment: Also, you could try with one of the other provers.  For example, install boolector and in cryptol `:set prover=boolector` then `:prove True`.

Comment: Oh wow... that did it. I wonder what the issue with cvc4 is... if you'd like to receive credit for solving the _cryptol_ issue, I'd be glad to award it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the conversation in the comments:

The "end of file" error mentioned in the question is commonly attributed to the prover of interest (CVC4 in this case) being only "partially installed" - in my cases this was always an issue with shared libraries that could be discovered by invoking the binary (cvc, boolector, etc) from the command line.  The ticket for the bug where the REPL would terminate is [on Cryptol's github](https://github.com/GaloisInc/cryptol/issues/105).  Fortunately, this issue was [fixed in upstream SBV](https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/commit/eb45e886fb1acb2833fc5f33b82d0f988686a0bc) and will appear in Cryptol's fork of SBV soon.

WRT AthanClark's particular case it is still unknown why and how CVC4 was failing when invoked by Cryptol - possibilities include cryptol invoking a different binary than the one we are expecting or environmental differences, such as the LD_LIBARARY path variable.  Either way, it sounds like he was able to use an alternative prover (`boolector`) successfully.

EDIT: If you can produce Athan's bug, where CVC works outside of SBV and not inside of SBV... and you live in Portland then shoot me a message, show up at my office and show me, I'd be interested.